# how to compress image without loosing its quality before uploading to database in php pdo mysql?

Tags: php, image

I'm presently working in online project..where users upload their images and that images will be first stored in server folder like "uploads" directory...and once the file will moved into that uploads directory..then the path will inserted into the mysql database using mysql query.
But the problem is..the images takes longer time to load on webpage...i want to reduce the image size before uploading into database and server..

here is my code

```
$upload_dir = 'user_images/'; // upload directory

        $imgExt = strtolower(pathinfo($imgFile,PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); // get image extension

        // valid image extensions
        $valid_extensions = array('jpeg', 'jpg', 'png', 'gif'); // valid extensions

        // rename uploading image
        $userpic = rand(1000,1000000).".".$imgExt;

        // allow valid image file formats
        if(in_array($imgExt, $valid_extensions)){           
            // Check file size '5MB'
            if($imgSize < 1000000){

                move_uploaded_file($tmp_dir,$upload_dir.$userpic);

            }
            else{
                $errMSG = "Sorry, your file is too large.";
            }
        }
        else{
            $errMSG = "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";        
        }
    }
```

And my query looks like..

```
if(!isset($errMSG))
    {


        $stmt = $user_home->runQuery("INSERT INTO cam_info (userID,
                                                            cam_name,
                                                cam_model,
                                            pixels,
                                    photoshoot,
                                    cam_rent,
                                    cam_img,
                                    mobile,
                                    state,
                                    address,
                                    upd_date,
                                    code )
                                                            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ");

        $stmt->bindParam(1,$id);
        $stmt->bindParam(2,$cam_name);
        $stmt->bindParam(3,$modelname);
        $stmt->bindParam(4,$pixel);
        $stmt->bindParam(5,$photoshoot);
        $stmt->bindParam(6,$rentpday);
        $stmt->bindParam(7,$userpic);
        $stmt->bindParam(8,$usermob);
        $stmt->bindParam(9,$state);
        $stmt->bindParam(10,$useraddrs);
        $stmt->bindParam(11,$upd_date);
        $stmt->bindParam(12,$ucode);

        if($stmt->execute())
        {

            $successMSG = "Record saved success";
        }
        else
        {
            $errMSG = "error while inserting....";
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking it is not good idea to upload images into the database - the database will grow up very rapidly and may leads to performance and maintain issues in the future.

Use database to keep the metadata about the pictures and keep the images on file system.

Comment: ya exactly @ino..I'm not storing images in database directly... i jst store image path thats it.but my issue is..i  jst want to reduze size before move to upload directory..

Comment: Then reformulate the question - original title was "how to compress image without loosing its quality before uploading to database in php pdo mysql?"

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the size is very general question as there are different aspects:

- reduce the size on file system, ie bytes
- reduce the size of dimension, ie pixels

To reduce the bytes you can:

- apply compression - applicable on jpg, png.
- convert the images in correct format - for screenshots is better png , for photos is better jpg
- resize the image dimensions - for viewing and sending over the internet you do not need lot of mega pixels
- reduce the number of colours
- remove alpha channel if not used
- remove EXIF information if not needed

To reduce the dimension:

- consider the main media where the images will be viewed, ie mobile vs desktop
- decide images max dimension of the image, up to 1024 px will be just fine to view on  most screens IMHO